# Why @Valid annotation not working when used inside service method argument but works for controller method?

Tags: spring-boot, javax.validation

I am having this `UserDto` class which I want to put under `@Valid`

```
@Getter @Setter
public class UserDto{

  @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty")
  private String name;

  @NotNull(message = "Provide a valid age")
  private Integer age;

}
```

I have some requirements where I can't put validation on controller method, but I need to do it on the service method.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/user")
public void create(@RequestBody UserDto user){
  userService.create(user);
}

public void create(@Valid UserDto user){
  System.out.println(user);
}
```

But this is not working. And if I put `@Valid` on the controller method, I do get the validation errors as expected.

Why so? Does serialization/deserialization has something to do with valition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually trigger spring validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702809/how-to-manually-trigger-spring-validation)

Comment: Have no tested but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56759120/6413377) works also:

Comment: @MattU Why would I need to trigger it manually? It should be handled itself.

Comment: @pirho No, same problem

Comment: No. The validation annotations are handled by the web layer (controller) when `@Valid` is present because it's configured to do so. The framework knows nothing of a "service layer", only a web layer. The annotation itself is not where the magic happens, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks. Manually triggering the validation did resolved the issue.